# setting size of UIImageView in a UITableView cell programmatically - what is the origin?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I'm trying to set the size of a UIImageView programmatically using:

```
[thisImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
```

I tried using x = 0, y = 0, but the UIImageView disappears.

More info on why I'm trying to do this. I'm trying to display a high-res image on an iPhone 4 without using the iOS 4 SDK (only using 3.2 SDK API calls). I have calls to see if I'm on an iPhone 4, so I'm trying to double the size of my UIImageView so that when I put the high-res UIImage in, it won't be grainy.

Comment: P.S. Will doubling the size of my UIImageView even achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what there is so special about iOS. Just use the same method you use with 3.2: imageNamed: ... it will take care of everything as long as your images are named properly (yourimagename.png and yourimagename@2x.png). Nothing fancy in the iOS 4 SDK here, just give the size you use in points as before.

If this is not suitable in your case, can you explain why?

Comment: Yes Eiko. The problem here is I am retrieving the image from a web server so I can dynamically change the image. The image I am sending is at the resolution I want to display on the iPhone 4 (e.g. my UIImageView in IB is 100 by 100 pixels and I am sending down an image that is 200 by 200 pixels). I tried sending down the image with the @2x suffix, but it didn't help. Would a solution be to send down two versions of the image, store them locally and then load it?

Comment: Hmm... "maybe". Downloading the image, saving it and using imageNamed: should work (don't use the @2x extension in that method, just the plain name). You should also be able to set the *scale factor* of the image manually.

Comment: But there are no devices < 4.0 with retina display anyway?!

Comment: I think you're confusing the SDK version with the OS version. iOS 4.0 (the OS) can run apps written using only the 3.2 SDK. Yet, I don't have access to all the nice functionality that is useful for retina displays in the 3.2 SDK even though I am running my apps on iOS 4.0+ devices.

Comment: You should compile *every* new app with the latest (read: 4.1) SDK. This also applies if you target 3.x devices. (And IIRC Apple only accepts builds with 4.x SDK as application uploads now)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to display a high-res image on an iPhone 4 without using the iOS 4 SDK (only using 3.2 SDK API calls)

Ouch. Don't do that.

Compile against 4.0, set the deployment target to 3.whatever.

When creating the image, check `[UIImage respondsToSelector:@selector(imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:)]`. If it does, then you can use [+[UIImage imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW37) to create a "scale 2" image, which will display correctly in a UIImageView on iPhone 4 (which has a "scale 2" screen).

If you really can't use the OS 4 SDK (you don't seem to state a reason why), then make the UIImageView smaller using the appropriate content mode (AspectFit/AspectFill/ScaleToFill), and set its frame to half the size in pixels (e.g. if the image is 100x100 px, set it to (CGSize){50,50}). This shrinks the image to half-size, but the double-res screen means you see it pixel-for-pixel.

Comment: If I use the 4.0 SDK, it enables backgrounding which breaks some functionality in my app. So I have to build and use the 3.2 SDK for now. Can you give me an example of your method for not using the OS 4 SDK? Thanks!

Comment: If app backgrounding is the only thing that you don't want in 4.0, just set `<key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key><true/>` in Info.plist.

Comment: Thanks tc - that looks interesting. Would it be okay for you to edit your post and show me an example of your no-4.0 SDK solution? Am I doing everything you specify if I am running on an iPhone 4? Which UIImageView do I change? The one in IB or programmatically when I check to see if I am running on an iPhone 4?

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is wrong. iPhone 4 works with points instead of pixels, which makes doubling the size troublesome. 1 point on old devices equals 4 pixels on iPhone 4, but is still used as 1 point.

When you create the frame you're not actually giving the API the pixel dimensions, but the point dimensions.

Comment: So is there no way to do this without using the 4.0 SDK?

Comment: Except an iPhone "point" is a lot smaller than the standard (PostScript) point of 1/72 inches. While Apple may call it a "point", it's a *terrible* name.